# Why does clickable view gain ripple after being selected?

Tags: android, animation, view, widget, click

I'm trying to use the theme attribute `colorControlHighlight` to apply default ripples to all clickable views in my app. Setting this theme attribute does change the ripple colors for controls such as buttons, tabs, etc.

My clickable views do not have a ripple effect on click initially. However, if I pass over the view by navigating with the arrow keys, pressing tab, etc., the view will then ripple when clicked.

What changes in a view after being selected using the arrow keys?